# How do I deploy three separate repos for 1 main domain and 2 subdomain on DigitalOcean?

Tags: javascript, subdomain, digital-ocean, mern

I'm fairly new to MERN and we're trying to deploy an app to DigitalOcean with one main domain and 2 subdomain.

we have the following setup for our app.

Three separate repos:

- Api (backend server for reading writing data)
- User (front end for users of our app)
- Admin (back end for admins)

We have 3 domains / subdomains registered in the following format:
`domain.com` (user)
`admin.domain.com` (admin)
`api.domain.com` (api)

Questions:

- How do we setup the droplet to accommodate this configuration? (user and admin side should point to api server)
- How do we deploy to the three separate repos from github to the one droplet while respecting the corresponding domain / subdomains?

Other considerations:
Do we need to use Nginx? Pm2?
We will be using mongodb as our database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Nginx as a web server. PM2 would not be a choice because it's not probably a server by itself.

[Refer Nginx Docs here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/)

Comment: Thank you. We finally managed to get it set up using Nginx, as per your suggestion.